# Compilation error for a binary_search on the attributes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, find, binary-search

I have a vector `v` of instances of the class `X`

```
class X
{
public:
  int attribute_1;
  ... 

  operator==(const int i){return this->attribute_1 == i;}
};

std::vector<X> v;
```

The vector `v` is sorted by the attribute `attribute_1`. I would like to perform a `binary_search` to test if a given integer matches the `attribute_1` of one of the instances of `X`. I tried

```
int elem = 12
bool isElementPresent = std::binary_search(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        elem,
        [](const X& right, const X& left){return right.attribute_1 < left.attribute_1;}
      )
    )
```

However it fails to compile. If I create an instance of `X` with `attribute_1` set to `elem`, then it works but I would like to avoid doing that (because 1. of the time to build the object of class `X` which has a lot of other attributes and 2. I would need to write a minimalist constructor and am scared I would use it elsewhere in the code by mistake).

I would have expected the `operator==` overloading would make it work. Why does it not work? Is there a solution that does not force me to create an instance of `X` with `attribute_1 = elem`?

Comment: You can't use a lambda. You need a class with two overloads of `operator()`, one taking `X` and `int ` and the other taking `int` and `X`. You need to be able to compare `elem` with actual vector elements, in both directions. Alternatively, construct an instance of `X` with `attribute_1` set to `elem`, and pass that to `std::binary_search`

Comment: It's not clear why you expect `operator==` to make any difference. Who is supposed to use it, and how? How is it expected to help? Anyway, it's not in fact used by `std::binary_search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it not work?

`std::binary_search` uses the comparison object also to check for equality. This is done similar to `comp(a, b) || comp(b, a)`. If that expression is false, then neither a is less than b nor b is less than a. Thus they must be equal.

Due to this usage the comparison object needs to accept objects of the collection as well as the value to search for as *both* the first and second parameter.

One solution is to use a "projection" class whose objects can be constructed both from the class in question as well as from the value you want to compare against. In the first case the projection class then extracts the value from the class member and stores it to its own member. In the other case it just copies the value to its own member.

Funny enough, this can even be made pretty general:

```
template<typename D, typename P, P> struct projection;

template<typename Data, typename Class, typename Return, Return (Class::*member_function) () const>
struct projection<Data, Return (Class::*) () const, member_function> {
 Data data;
 projection (Class const & object)
  : data ((object.*member_function)()) {}
/* template<typename X>
 projection (X&& input)
  : data (std::forward<X>(input)) {}*/
 projection (Data d) : data (d) {}
};
```

This projection class is then used as the two parameters of the comparison object used by the search. [Example](http://ideone.com/pMQist):

```
struct Item {
 int x;
 int get () const { return x; }
};


int main () {
 Item items [] = {1,2,3,4,5,99};
 using P = projection<int, decltype(&Item::get), &Item::get>;
 auto compare = [](P const & left, P const & right) {
               return left.data < right.data; };
 std::cout << std::binary_search(
      std:: begin (items), std::end(items),
      4, compare)
    << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::binary_search(
      std:: begin (items), std::end(items),
      44, compare)
    << std::endl;
}
```

Above code uses constant member functions ("getters"), but with the following specialisation it [also works with pointers to members](http://ideone.com/SBN2nI):

```
template<typename Data, typename Class, typename Member, Member (Class::*member_pointer)>
struct projection<Data, Member (Class::*), member_pointer> {
 Data data;
 projection (Class const & object)
  : data (object.*member_pointer) {}
/* template<typename X>
 projection (X&& input)
  : data (std::forward<X>(input)) {}*/
 projection (Data d) : data (d) {}
};
```